# Converting recipe from pellet hops to wet hops

Tags: hops, all-grain, smash

I have several wild hop vines growing near me, and I'd like to try a few SMaSH brews to see what the flavour is like. I have some recipes, but they all use pellet hops.

What is a good conversion from pellet to wet hops so I can figure out how much I need to harvest and use on brew day?

Comment: Please see updated answer. I had to double check the rate of utilization between pellets and dry hops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pellet hops are considered 15% more efficient at utilization than dry hops (according to Charles Faram) meaning for 100g of pellets you would need 115g of dry hops for the same recipe.

Using the information in this [answer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/what-is-wet-hopping-and-how-does-it-differ-from-dry) you can then convert the weight of dry hops to wet hops. The answer there says:

> "Fresh hops weigh 4-6 times more than their dry counterpart, so this
>   needs to be taken into account when weighing. For example, if you
>   normally dry hop with 15g (1/2oz), then you'll need to wet hop with around
>   60-90g (2-3oz) of fresh hops."

So if you have 100g of pellet hops in your recipe, convert that to 115g dry hops then convert that to 460-690 wet hops.

Comment: As I got a down vote with no explanation I should probably explain that Charles Faram and Simply Hops, hop merchants in the UK, both told me that pellet hops are on average 50% more efficient than dry hops. Can't see why else someone would down vote it, but please explain if so.

Comment: I'd like to know where the hop merchants got their information then.  I've never before heard the term "efficiency" used for hops.

Comment: I guess from testing. The information I have written in my notes from telephone conversations with them is as so: "Leaf hops are around 20% efficient. Pellet hops are around 30% efficient. This means you would have to use 50% more Leaf hops to imbue the same flavour as given by Pellet hops."

Comment: That is in reference to T90 pellets, which they both supply. Perhaps older pellets weren't as efficient?

Comment: I still have no idea where the term "efficiency" comes into play.  Typically hops are discussed in terms of "utilization" which is specifically in reference to isomerization of alpha acids.  I've never seen "efficiency" numbers discussed in reference to alpha nor to dissolution of any other chemical constituents.

Comment: Well I've just rang up and much to my embarrassment my previous notes on what was said were wrong. Spoke to the same guy and he has confirmed you would get 15% better utilization. I asked him to say 1-5 or 5-0 to cut out any issues with accents. I will update my answer. Next time you downvote an answer of mine could you please comment why, so I have a chance to respond or update it.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Utliisation is literally just another word for efficiency. The maths is identical, and the concept is too. I think taking issue with the term efficiency is pedantic rather than useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have dried dozens of batches of freshly harvested homegrown hops to learn that they average 20-25% solids or overall about 22% solids, which means the primary multiplication factor should be 4.5 (i.e., 4.5 times 0.22 = 1).

Most sources say utilization from pellets is about 10% more than whole hops.  So this means the total should also be multiplied by 1.1.

1.1 times 4.5 = a grand factor of 4.95 or about 5.

I have used this factor many times, with great results.